# Define graph in Prolog: edge and path, finding if there is a path between two vertices

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, transitive-closure

I'm very new to Prolog. I defined in `graph.pl` the following graph:

[image: graph]

And here's my Prolog code:

```
edge(a,e).
edge(e,d).
edge(d,c).
edge(c,b).
edge(b,a).
edge(d,a).
edge(e,c).
edge(f,b).
path(X,X).
path(X,Y):- edge(X,Z) ; path(Z,Y).
```

I understand it like this: *there is a path between vertex `X` and vertex `Y` only if there is an edge between vertex `X` and vertex `Z` AND there is a path between vertex `Z` and vertex `Y`* (some kind of recursion).

Is that right for the presented graph? When I ask Prolog about the path between vertex `A` and vertex `F` it gives me `true` ...  which isn't even right! What might be wrong in this code?

Comment: `;` is OR. `,` is AND. So your `path` clause is incorrect.

Comment: @mbratch: When I changed `;` to `,` Prolog hung out... giving no answer. For my graph the answer should be false/no.

Comment: The `;` is still incorrect and must be `,`. The other problem is that the code doesn't handle the issue of paths that are in a circuit, so it can go round and round the circuit until stack overflow before it gets to a solution. You would need to collect a list of "where you've been" to make sure you don't repeat paths.

Comment: @mbratch: Ok,thanks, it makes sense now. But how should appropriate rule for my graph look like?

Comment: One way is to have your rule collect a list of edges that you've traveled and not choose them if you've been there already. If you google 'prolog graph', you'll find several examples online that have this exact problem all spelled out, such as http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html.

Comment: I restored your original code, so all the comments (and your question) make sense (i.e. are in sync).

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133) for a general solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cycles in the graph. You need to track what nodes you're visiting, and check them. Try this, using a helper predicate with an accumulator to track the visited nodes:

```
path(A,B) :-   % two nodes are connected, if
  walk(A,B,[]) % - if we can walk from one to the other,
  .            % first seeding the visited list with the empty list

walk(A,B,V) :-       % we can walk from A to B...
  edge(A,X) ,        % - if A is connected to X, and
  not(member(X,V)) , % - we haven't yet visited X, and
  (                  % - either
    B = X            %   - X is the desired destination
  ;                  %   OR
    walk(X,B,[A|V])  %   - we can get to it from X
  )                  %
  .                  % Easy!

edge(a,e).
edge(e,d).
edge(d,c).
edge(c,b).
edge(b,a).
edge(d,a).
edge(e,c).
edge(f,b).
```

Comment: The simpler way to get it done. Maybe memberchk/2 is preferable to member/2.

Comment: This predicate has some surprising practical applications. With a few simple changes, it can be used as an [English-to-Prolog translator](https://gist.github.com/jarble/05034095e3e208022c9ece90f03d00c1).

Answer (score 7):

The format you use (edge/2) make sense for learning about Prolog, and you should follow mbratch' advice about the tutorial.

Actually, there are good alternatives already available, in some case with useful predicates ready to go: for instance, in library([ugraph](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs)), there is [reachable](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reachable/3)/3. Now, with your data, this path/2 predicate

```
path(X,Y) :-
    findall(A-B, edge(A,B), Es),
    vertices_edges_to_ugraph([],Es,G),
    reachable(X,G,Path),
    member(Y,Path).
```

does

```
?- path(a,X).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c ;
X = d ;
X = e.
```

Let's see what it means:

```
findall(A-B, edge(A,B), Es)
```

put in Es all edges, with notation as required by library,

```
vertices_edges_to_ugraph([],Es,G)
```

builds in G the corresponding graph

```
reachable(X,G,Path)
```

make a list Path of all vertices reachable (duh) from X

```
member(Y,Path)
```

see if Y is present in Path.

Since I queried with Y *free*, I get all reachable vertices from X, that I bound to `a`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in knowing *if* a path exists—but not necessarily in the actual path(s)—compute the [*transitive closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) of the binary relation `edge/2`.

Luckily for you, [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) is a common idiom in [prolog](/questions/tagged/prolog)!

To express the irreflexive transitive closure of `edge/2`, use  [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure)—defined in the earlier question "[Definition of Reflexive Transitive Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure)":

```
?- closure(edge, X, Y).
   X = a, Y = e
;  X = a, Y = d
;  X = a, Y = c
;  ...
```

Note that `closure/3` has very good termination properties.

If all clauses of `edge/2` are ground facts, `closure(edge, _, _)` terminates universally! Look:

```
?- closure(edge, _, _), false.
false.
```

Comment: `edge(X,s(X)).` terminates universally, yet `closure(edge,0,X)` describes an infinite set that can only be described with infinitely many answers. Thus non-termination!

Comment: Terrific! And terrifying, too. Will edit to clarify! Thx!

Answer (score 2):

It is checking in a cycle!
I executed the example with the `trace.` command before hand, and saw, that the program returns to the problem to find the path from a to f after cycling around.
path(a,f) needs path(e,f) to be true, following in short notation we need to be true:

(d,f), (c,f), (b,f), an then (a,f) again.

To resolv the loop you need a mechanism to prevent loop. My first Idea would be to keep a list of node-names and also check, if the list does not include the current X while checking the path.