# Find path and its length between nodes in a graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, shortest-path, failure-slice, non-termination

I'm trying to solve this problem and I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21196849/3673430) answer, but my problem is with infinte looping even if I've used a visited node list.

Let's see my two tries:

```
edge(1,2).
edge(1,4).
edge(1,3).
edge(2,3).
edge(2,5).
edge(3,4).
edge(3,5).
edge(4,5).


% ------ simple path finding in a directed graph

% -----  simple exploration

path0(A,B, Result) :-
    path0(A, B, [], Result).

path0(A, B, _, [e(A,B)]):- 
    edge(A,B).    
path0(A, B, Visited, [e(A,X)|Path]):-
    edge(A, X), dif(X, B),
    \+ member(X, Visited),
    path0(X, B, [A|Visited], Path ).    


%---- 1. exploration and length    

path(A, B, _, [e(A,B)], 1):- 
    edge(A,B).    
path(A, B, Visited, [e(A,X)|Path], Length):-
    edge(A, X),
    \+ member(X, Visited),
    length(Path, L),        % ERR: Path refers to a open list
    Length is L + 1,
    path(X, B, [A|Visited], Path, _).

% --- 2. not working

path2(A,B, Result, Length) :-
    path2(A, B, [], Result, Length).

path2(A, B, [], [e(A,B)], 1):- 
    edge(A,B).    
path2(A, B, Visited, [e(A,X)|Path], Length):-
    edge(A, X), dif(X, B),
    \+ member(X, Visited),
    path2(X, B, [A|Visited], Path, Len),
    Length is Len + 1.
```

Which give me similar answers, i.e.:

```
 ?- path(1,3, Path, Length).
Path = [e(1, 3)],
Length = 1 ;
Path = [e(1, 2), e(2, 3)],
Length = 2 ;
```

And then the Swi-Prolog IDE freezes.

- What should I define as the base case ?
- <s>Why is the second implementation looping, if it's the case, even if I used the visited node list and the dif() to be sure to avoid unification go back and forth?</s> I misstyped the function name.

I would like to get rid of the length/2 use.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

So, I figured out this should be the cleaner way of doing it, even if I would like something more similar to the second implementation which would be easier to transform in a shortest path problem solver, since it would be just a min{ pathLengths } from the first call of path3/4.

```
% ---- 3. working    
%   
min(A,B,A):- A =< B, !.       % for future use (shortest path)
min(_,B,B).

path3(From, To, Path, Len):-    
    path0(From, To, [], Path),
    length(Path, Len).
    %min(Len, MinLength, ?)
```

---

And this is the corrected version of the second implementation path2:

```
% --- 2. 
% errors: 1. in base case I have to return Visited trough _, 
%             I can't pass a void list []
%         2. dif(X,B) is unuseful since base case it's the first clause

path2(A,B, Result, Length) :-
    path2(A, B, [], Result, Length).

path2(A, B, _, [e(A,B)], 1):-      % If an edge is found
    edge(A,B).    
path2(A, B, Visited, [e(A,X)|Path], Length):-
    edge(A, X),  
    %tab(1),write(A),write('-'),write(X),
    \+ member(X, Visited),
    %tab(1),write([A|Visited]),write(' visited'),nl,
    path2(X, B, [A|Visited], Path, Len),
    Length is Len + 1.
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) for a general solution. If you want to limit the path to a certain length, add the goal `length(Path, N)` either before (if you know `N`) or thereafter, if you simply want to know the length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why both `path/4` and `path2/4` expose similar non-termination behavior is because both use the very same auxiliary predicate `path/5`. You probably meant `path2/5` instead:

```
path2(A,B, Result, Length) :-
    path(A, B, [], Result, Length).
 %  ^^^^ replace by path2
```

Maybe first, let's look why your `path/4` definition loops. To see this, I will insert goals **`false`** into your program. These goals will reduce the number of inferences. When the remaining fragment still loops, we can be sure that we see a part that is responsible for non-termination.  After some experiments, I found the following fragment, called a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice):

```
edge(1,2).
edge(1,4) :- false.
edge(1,3) :- false.
edge(2,3) :- false.
edge(2,5) :- false.
edge(3,4) :- false.
edge(3,5) :- false.
edge(4,5) :- false.

path(A,B, Result, Length) :-
    path(A, B, [], Result, Length), false.

path(A, B, _, [e(A,B)], 1):- false,
    edge(A,B).
path(A, B, Visited, [e(A,X)|Path], Length):-
    edge(A, X),
    \+ member(X, Visited),
    length(Path, L), false,
    Length is L + 1,
    path(X, B, [A|Visited], Path, _).
```

So essentially it's the use of the `length/2` predicate. As long as the length of the path is not fixed, this fragment will not terminate. So for the query

```
?- path(1, 3, Path, N).
```

The `Path` is not limited in its length and thus `length/2` will find infinitely many solutions - and thus will not terminate.

But, after all, why do you want to know the length anyway? The path argument describes it already implicitly.

For your definition `path/4,5` consider what the query

```
?- path(1, X, Path, N).
```

should produce as an answer. Should `Path = [1]` be a solution, too? It's a bit a question of the exact definition of a path/walk. I think it should.

For a generic solution, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868). With it, you can define the predicates that you are interested in like so:

```
yourpath(A,B, Path, N) :-
   path(edge, Path, A,B),
   length(Path, N).
```

But, I would rather not add the extra argument about the length of the path. You can add that information later anytime anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry for that distraction error. What do you mean with "So essentially it's the use of the length/2 predicate. As long as the length of the path is not fixed, this fragment will terminate."? At every recursion step the simple path list is fixed, finite and indeed correctly calculated. Adding a cut after the base case terminates if I give the first edge, but not in the other cases. I'm adding the length/distance just as an exercise with the goal of returning just the shortest one, as next exercise.

Comment: @bastaPasta: I forgot a not. See fix above: As long as ... this fragment will **not** terminate.

Comment: @bastaPasta: "At every recursion step the simple path list is fixed" That is inaccurate for a query like `path(1,3, Path, N)`. Here, the length is not fixed within recursion. There are infinitely many paths.

Comment: @bastePaste: w.r.t. cut: leave it out by any means, it will reduce the set of valid solutions to some arbitrary case. Cuts are extremely hard to use correctly. Better leave them out at all as a beginner.

Comment: So the lengths that prolog returns are just those ones coming from the terminated unification, while there are uninstantiated "edges" which don't permit termination ?

Comment: @bastaPasta: The best is to look at the fragment alone. There is not much left. No recursion etc. Only one unification `Path = [edge(A,X)|Path2]`. The remaining `Path2` is left uninstantiated and it is that variable that occurs in `length(Path2,L)`. Just try it out as a query alone! `?- length(Path2, L).`

Comment: I added a third solution which seems to work. Is it likely path2 has the same problem on "\+ member(X, Visited)," since neither Visited is fixed? Tomorrow I'll try to find the failure-slice. Thanks.

Comment: @bastaPasta: There are very exotic cases where `\+ member(X, Visited)` will not work, whereas the definition linked above will work.