# Prolog Representation for Parallel Line Theorem Reasoning

Tags: prolog

I am using prolog for reasoning about theorems for parallel lines.

That is, AB || EF and CD || EF, which leads to AB || CD.

The current code ensures that AB || CD is true, but BA || CD is false.
Is there any way to make BA || CD is also true?

M and N are to control the number of executions, which I guess is not related to the problem.

Here is my code:

```
seg(A,B):-seg(B,A).
parallel(seg(A,B),seg(C,D),N):-M is N - 1,M >= 0,parallel(seg(A,B),seg(E,F),M),parallel(seg(C,D),seg(E,F),M).
parallel(A,B,N):-M is N - 1,M >= 0,parallel(B,A,M).
parallel(A,B,N):-M is N - 1,M >= 0,parallel(A,B,M).
parallel(seg(a,b),seg(e,f),0).
parallel(seg(c,d),seg(e,f),0).
```

The query I executed:

```
parallel(seg(a,b),seg(c,d),2). ------true
parallel(seg(b,a),seg(c,d),2). ------false,should be true
```

I know I can use this method to solve the problem, but the number of rules needed is 2^N.

```
parallel(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)) :- parallel_base(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)).
parallel(seg(A, B), seg(D, C)) :- parallel_base(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)).
parallel(seg(B, A), seg(C, D)) :- parallel_base(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)).
parallel(seg(B, A), seg(D, C)) :- parallel_base(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)).
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to learn about [freeze/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=freeze/2) then realize that [constraints](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clp) bundles up most the details for you.

Comment: Rather than immediately counting - create a list of the parallel-to-this-segment segments, then the count is simply the list length.

Comment: First, state what kind of inference rules (independently of a Prolog encoding) you intend to use. What about AB||BC & A≠C then AB||AC ?

Comment: @false I'm not considering the common line at the moment, just three parallel lines.

Comment: Why have `0` in the *parallel* rules?

Comment: @brebs  0 means that this is the 0th step of the derivation. parallel(seg(a,b),seg(e,f),2) means whether AB || EF can be deduced in 2 steps.

Comment: Putting the zero in the `parallel` rules is inappropriate. This all sounds very similar to https://www.google.com/search?q=prolog+path+edge , e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161624/define-graph-in-prolog-edge-and-path-finding-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-ve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to mention - rather than:

```
  ((A=W,B=X);(A=X,B=W)),
  ((C=Y,D=Z);(C=Z,D=Y)),
```

... a neater alternative is to enforce the convention of the lower (or equal) value being first, using e.g.:

```
lower_upper(X, Y, L, U) :-
    (   X @< Y
    ->  L = X, U = Y
    ;   L = Y, U = X
    ).
```

This will help to reduce the amount of unwanted choicepoints, and improve code clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parallel(seg(A, B), seg(C, D)) :- 
  ((A=W,B=X);(A=X,B=W)),
  ((C=Y,D=Z);(C=Z,D=Y)),
  parallel_base(seg(W, X), seg(Y, Z)).
```

This uses the nonrecursive relation `parallel_base`, allowing the endpoints of the lines to be given in any order. I didn't use your `seg`/1 predicate because it's recursive and you may get endless recursion. (I recommend you comment it out, or make it nonrecursive in the same way you made `parallel`/2 nonrecursive by using `parallel_base`.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This will solve my problem.